# Persisting Game Actor Objects

Tags: xna, persistence, polyglot-persistance

This question pertains to a game I have been developing, but I believe it is a pretty generic concept for which I have not been able to find a clear answer.

I have been trying to figure out how to serialize actors (objects in a game world) to a file, ***dynamically and at arbitrary times***.

### Context

To understand my question you need to know how the world is generally constructed.  The game is a cell-based world with 3 dimensions divided into smaller, more manageable sections that I'll  refer to as chunks.  The terrain info is all fixed known length, and I can serialize that information just fine, simply writing/reading to/from a world file with the appropriate offset whenever that chunk needs to be loaded into memory (say a player gets near it).  That's all well and good until I have to deal with actors and writing them to a single file.

### The Problem

I know that ISerializable is an incredibly useful resource for actually obtaining the data from the actors, but the problem I'm having is committing that to disk dynamically.  By that I mean inserting/removing actors from the middle of a big file containing all actors.  It would be a lot easier if I could serialize the entire game state and actor tree, but I need to be able to do this on small sections of the world at a time.  Some sections will have no actors, some will have many (say up to a couple hundred).  These sections are being loaded and saved as the players move around the world.  Furthermore, the number of actors and size of their data will change over the course of the game, so I cannot handle it like I do the terrain.  I need a way of committing the actor quickly, where I can find it quickly later and am not wasting a lot of file space.  One thing that may be of use is that all actors in a chunk are serialized/de-serialized at once, never individually.

Note: These worlds can get very large (16k x 16k x 6) and therefore easily have millions of actors in all.

### The Question

Is a database really the best way to do this?  I am not opposed to implementing one, but that is an involved process and I want to be sure it is a recommended course of actions before I continue.  It seems like there might be serious performance implications.

Comment: You should look into using a NoSQL database; might simplify your life...

Comment: I use Protobuf-net for a similar activity.  This serializes a single or several instances into a small file,

Comment: @rae1 I was looking at Redis, but being able to find support could be an issue.  I might try out a thicker DB first per Aron's answer and if I really run into soul-crushing performance issues even with threading, I'll make the leap to NoSQL.

Comment: Look into [FoundationDB](https://foundationdb.com/). It seems to have the best of both worlds.

Comment: @rae Yes! I'd love to send a newbie off to write an interop layer with a C API. FoundationDB doesn't have .net bindings!

Comment: Actually FoundationDB has APIs for Ruby, Python, Java, JavaScript. And even then I don't see what's so scary about a C API if it does the job. And lastly, I wouldn't call OP a 'newbie'... that's just wrong =)

Comment: @rae1 note the lack of .net or C#. Given that the OP tagged the question with `C#` and `XNA` I went and assumed that he would find Ruby/Python/Java/Javascript bindings pretty useless. The only one that works with .net would be C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tradition database (RDBMS) is not always the right way to go. But alas, you ARE trying to persist data.

Most IT professionals will likely guide you towards a traditional database, simply because for us it ISN'T involved. It is out bread and butter. Further more, there are hundreds of libraries that make our lives easier, the latest generation of which are the full blown `ORM`s.

However, as you have noted, a full blown RDBMS is a little heavy weight for your application (depending on your particular scaling needs). So I'll suggests a few alternatives.

- MongoDB
- RavenDB
- CouchDB
- Cassandra
- Redis

Now, it IS true that in many ways, these are much lighter weight than RDBMSs. However these so called NoSQL (I picked Document stores, since they seem to be the closest match to your requirements) are somewhat immature. That is not to say they are buggy, and unreliable (they have higher reliability than RDBMSs), but people don't really know how to work with them.

Again, I need to qualify that statement. RDBMS have several decades of research and best practices behind them. There are vast swathes of plug-ins to the tool chains of each implementation. Every single contributor in SO knows how to use a DB well. But, none of those things is true with NoSQL.

TLDR

So it really boils down to this. YES RDBMS (traditional DBs) are complex, like a modern road car. But like a road car (which you buy), these exists the infrastructure to support them.

The alternative is a NoSQL database, which is like building a small electric go scooter. Yes its simpler. But you take it to a car shop, and they'll still have no clue.

Finally

My advice. Use an off the shelf ORM with a RDBMS. The current generation of ORM can pretty much hide your database from you. The setup won't be very performant (you won't be doing microsecond algo trading with it), but it should be enough for your needs.

Comment: Understood.  So while things like Redis (the one I was looking at) potentially could be a lot faster, it would be like sailing into uncharted waters, with no lifeboat.  I think what I'll do is try a thicker DB (but still thin, ...sqlite?) and throw loading/unloading into a side thread since I already have a system in place for handling chunks in various states.   I do appreciate the verbosity of your answer.

Comment: My experience with SqLite has been with .net has been pretty poor. The open source driver for Sqlite for .net is little more than a shim for the native api. The result each individual row/column (cell) you pull down is an interop, and has MASSIVE perf issues.